# List as key for a key value store

Tags: java, hash, key-value-store

I want to store key value pair in data base where key is a list of Integers or a set of Integers.

The use case that I have has the below steps

1. I will get a list of integers
2. I will need to check if that list of integers (as a key) is already present in the DB
3. If this is present, I will need to pick up the value from the DB

There are certain computations that I need to do if the list of integers (or set of integers) is not there in the DB already, if this there then I just want to pass the value and avoid the computations.

I am thinking of keeping the data in a key value store but I want the key to be specifically a list or set of integers.

I have thought about below options

**Option A**

Generate a unique hash for the list of integers and store that as key in key/value store

Problem:
I will have hash collision which will break my use case. I believe there is no way to generate hash with uniqueness 100% of the time.

This will not work.

If there is away to generate a unique hash (100%) times then that is the best way.

**Option B**

Create an immutable class with List of integers or Set of integers and store that as a key for my key value store.

Please share any feasible ways to achieve the need.

Comment: You've ruled out option A. Have you tried option B?

Comment: I need to still figure out the DB (key/value store) that I can use for this purpose. A key/value store that will support Object (Set, List or Custom Object) as key. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @ctimus - I feel Collections.unModifiableList() or Collections.unModifiableSet() can partially help you achieve it. But the question on how that shall be handled at DB level still remains. If the key that you want to use is heterogenous, then you can use a custom object. Just my two cents

Comment: How is the hash duplication a problem? If you have a collision, you can still iterate the list to check if they're equal.

Comment: @KavithaKarunakaran The key is not heterogenous. It will always contain unique integers of different count. So better way to think of it is as Set of Integers.

Comment: @daniu If there is a collision then I will get a value for a wrong Set of Integers.

For ex:

Say for 11111, 2222, 33333 I am generating a hash say ABC123 and a value Val1 ( storing ASC123 and Val1 as key value in DB)
and now say for 5555,6666,7777 also I got the same hash ABC123, then my DB query will give value Val1 which will be wrong and I won't have a way to check unless every time I scan through the list to compare. Is that what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2):

You don’t need to do anything special:

```
Map<List<Integer>, String> keyValueStore = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> key = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
keyValueStore.put(key, "foo");
```

All JDK collections implement sensible `equals()` and `hashCode()` that is based solely on the contents of the list.

Comment: Since performance seems to be an issue, OP should do some experiments with different load factors of `HashMap` compared to a `TreeMap`, where `contains()` is guaranteed to run in O(log(n)). After reading a lot about `equals()` the last two weeks, i’m astonished that in deed implementations of `Set::equals()` and `List::equals()` are sensible.

Comment: I initially thought the fact that those keys are mutable could "break" the Map, but it's the *hash at insertion time* that is retained, not the object reference. So you can reuse the same object as a key, as long as it has different values.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you. I would like to share some more findings.

I now tried the below further to what I mentioned in my earlier post.

I added the below documents in Mongodb

```
db.products.insertMany([
{
    mapping: [1, 2,3],
    hashKey:'ABC123',
    date: Date()
},
{
    mapping: [4, 5],
    hashKey:'ABC45'  ,
    date: Date()
},
{
    mapping: [6, 7,8],
    hashKey:'ABC678' ,
    date: Date()
},
{
    mapping: [9, 10,11],
    hashKey:'ABC91011', 
    date: Date()
},
{
    mapping: [1, 9,10],
    hashKey:'ABC1910',
    date: Date()
},
{
    mapping: [1, 3,4],
    hashKey:'ABC134',
    date: Date()
},
{
    mapping: [4, 5,6],
    hashKey:'ABC456',
    date: Date()
}  
]);
```

When I am now trying to find the mapping I am getting expected results

```
> db.products.find({ mapping: [4,5]}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d4640281be52eaf11b25dfc"),
    "mapping" : [
        4,
        5
    ],
    "hashKey" : "ABC45",
    "date" : "Sat Aug 03 2019 19:17:12 GMT-0700 (PDT)"
}
```

*The above is giving the right result as the mapping [4,5] (insertion order retained) is present in the DB*

```
> db.products.find({ mapping: [5,4]}).pretty();
```

*The above is giving no result as expected as the mapping [5,4] is not present in the DB. The insertion order is retained*

**So it seems the "mapping" as List is working as expected.**

I used Spring Data to read from MongoDB that is running locally.

The format of the document is

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "hashKey" : "ABC123",
    "mapping" : [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "_class" : "com.spring.mongodb.document.Mappings"
}
```

I inserted 1.7 million records into DB using *org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner*

Then the query similar to my last example:

```
db.mappings.find({ mapping: [1,2,3]})
```

is taking average 1.05 seconds to find the mapping from 1.7 M records.

Please share if you have any suggestion to make it faster and how fast can I expect it to run.

I am not sure about create, update and delete performance as yet.